# Rendering Â In Front of Special Characters

Tags: php

I am reading in a string from my CMS that contains the copyright sign `®`. However, when I render this string to my site, I get an `Â` right before the copyright sign. For example, I have `Microsoft®` in my CMS, but it renders `MicrosoftÂ®`.

```
$title = (string) $myString;
$title = htmlentities($title,ENT_NOQUOTES,'UTF-8',false);
$title = str_replace(array('&lt;','&gt;'),array('<','>'), $title);
var_dump( $title );
```

Answer (score 4):

The character code for "Copyright Sign" is `0xA9`. However, this is outside the range of `0x00` to `0x7F`.

Therefore, in a single-byte character set such as ISO-8859-1 or Windows-1252, it works fine.

But in a multi-byte set like Unicode, it it represented as `0xC2 0xA9`. It is coincidence that the second byte is the same as the original, nothing more.

To fix, you need to make sure your encoding is consistent. One solution would be to make sure your HTML document has `UTF-8` as its `charset`.

Comment: Our HTML document has `UTF-8` set.

Answer (score 0):

try utf8_encoding then utf8_decoding if you "move" the text arround. 
and also check if in the header of the html you are using the right encoding.

Note that if you already have that in the database messed up you will not be able to revert it.

Answer (score 0):

Check the php `[default_charset][1]` setting in php.ini or use `ini_set()` in your php file

```
<?php

ini_set("default_charset", "utf-8");

?>
```

Set the the encoding to your php files to `utf8`

Set the html meta tag:

```
<meta equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```