# PHP - Rendering Â In Front of Special Characters - Encoding Issue?

Tags: php

Branching from my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15147874/rendering-in-front-of-special-characters).

In my CMS (CQ5), I am grabbing values that are entered with ASCII encoding. Sometimes some of these strings entered contains special characters (ie - copyright `®`) an odd character  `Â` would be inserted in front of it when I output it in PHP.

I looked into encoding it into UTF-8, but that did not work. I have tried the following:

```
//$title is the CMS input that contains special characters
$strA = iconv('ASCII', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', $title);
$strB = mb_convert_encoding($title, "UTF-8");
$strC = utf8_encode($title);
```

Comment: Sounds typical for the data being **UTF-8** encoded but the client incorrectly interpreting the data as ISO-8859-1.

Comment: How would I solve this problem? I already have the following meta tag in each HTML page: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`

Comment: Then the data is probably double encoded. You certainly should not use `utf8_encode`. Ever. Read [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/) and [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/).

Answer (score 1):

If your strings contain a copyright symbol then *they are not ASCII!*

They're either already in UTF-8, or something like ISO-8859-1.  It may be possible to figure out which by looking at the actual byte encoding of the strings.

You must also ensure that your CMS generates the right HTML character set tag, so that the users browsers know which character set is in use, i.e.

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
...
</head>
```

The `Â` character is a common artefact caused by sending UTF-8 but not telling the receiver that you've done so.

Comment: When I check the encoding of the inputted CMS string, it outputs as ASCII. `var_dump ( mb_detect_encoding($title) );`

Comment: I believe the data is flowed from CMS -> PHP (Symfony) -> Browser. Would it be possible to convert the string in the PHP level?

Comment: How would I tell the receiver (I'm assuming the web browser) that it should be UTF-8? At the top of each HTML file, I have this tag: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`.

Comment: If `mb_detect_encoding()` says that a string with the special `(C)` character in it is ASCII it's lying.

Comment: @icu222much your meta tag is correct - the abbreviated one I had shown is for HTML5.

Comment: Thank you. My client (browser) knows that it should be UTF-8 from the meta tag should it not?